Install Instauto on Raspberry Pi failed
im trying to install Instauto from this github: https://github.com/mifi/instauto
I followed the setup and installed it successfull on my raspberry pi and edited the example.js.
Everytime im running it on my raspberry pi it failes with the following message. Does anybody know why it fails and how to fix it? I tried it with different solutions but nothing worked.

I tried it with different solutions. I read that on Raspberry Pi you need a arm7 chromium package to work with pupeteer. I tried to install and it doesnt work.
I changed the code lines exactly like on the setup for raspberry pi.
Error Message
